# How to test exception with Junit 4 and Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, junit

I have the following function which I want to test:

```
   def filterFoo(FooColumnName: String, Foo: Seq[Any]): DataFrame = {
      /* validate input parameters */
      require(Option(FooColumnName).isDefined)
      require(Option(Foo).isDefined)
      require(df.columns.contains(FooColumnName))

      df.filter(col(FooColumnName).isin(Foo:_*))
```

I have written the following test:

```
  @Test(expected = classOf[IllegalArgumentException])
  def testFilterFoorWrongColumnName(): Unit ={

    val df = data.toDF(columns:_*)
    df.filterFoo(FooColumnName = "foo", Foo = competitors)

  }
```

If FooColumnName does not exists in Data frame it would throw IllegalArgumentException. I am getting this exception but it is failing the test because of this. I get this error when I run the test:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `filterDomain` and `filterFoo` are the same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to reify the exception into a value, which, thankfully, is something that is extremely idiomatic in Scala.  `scala.util.Try` is in the standard library and exceptionally useful for this:

```scala
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success, Try }

@Test(expected = classOf[IllegalArgumentException])
def testFilterFoorWrongColumnName(): Unit ={
  val df = data.toDF(columns:_*)
  val attempt = Try {  // note the capital T, this is not the keyword try...
    df.filterFoo(FooColumnName = "foo", Foo = competitors)
  }

  // apologies, I don't know JUnit at all...
  attempt match {
    case _: Success =>
      failTheTest  // should have been a failure

    case Failure(ex) =>  // ex is the thrown exception
      // can check that the exception is an IllegalArgumentException or whatever
      doChecksOnException
  }
}
```

How it works is that a `Try[T]` is either a `Success` wrapping a `T` or a `Failure` wrapping a `Throwable`.  `Try { }` wraps the code in a `try` block and catches the exception; if it's a `NonFatal` exception, that exception goes into the `Failure`.  There are some other good reasons to use `Try` (it has some nicely compositional properties), but those are out of the scope of this answer.